# Copying text from accordion triggers click button

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, accordion

Hello I have this siple accordion, and I have an issue, that whenever i copy text from accordion, click event listener triggers and closes the accordion.
I would like to make it work without using jQuery

How could I fix it?
and how would I make it , so when i click somewhere else than on .question / .answer it would close automaticaly? i tried adding event listener to window, but after a long time of not figuring out how to makeit work I gave up.

here is my codepen : [https://codepen.io/drabfi/pen/LYrBxzWhttps://codepen.io/drabfi/pen/LYrBxzW](https://codepen.io/drabfi/pen/LYrBxzW)

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h2 class="accordion-title">Frequently asked questions</h2>
  <div class="content-container active">
    <div class="question">What is the return Policy</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="question">Where can you find us</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="question">Some other text</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".content-container");

for(let i=0;i<accordion.length;i++){
  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
   if(this.classList.contains("active")){
      accordion.forEach((panel)=>panel.classList.remove("active"));
   }else{
      accordion.forEach((panel)=>panel.classList.remove("active"));
      this.classList.add("active");
   }
  })
}
```

```scss
.accordion{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    border-color: #fff;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    &-title{
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .content-container
        .question{
            padding: 1rem 0;
            font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        position: relative;
        &::after{
            content: "+";
            position: absolute;
            right: -5px;

        }
        }
        .answer{
           padding-top: 1rem;
           font-size: 22px;
           line-height: 1.5;
           width: 100%; 
           height: 0px;
           overflow: hidden;
           transition: all .5s;
        }
}

// js styling link

.accordion .content-container.active{
    .question{

        &::after{
            content: "-";
            font-size: 2rem;
            transition: .5s;
        }
    }
    .answer{
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

I would be very happy to see the solutions so I could move on from this spot. Thank you for any advices.

Comment: have you tried focusout events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to learn a bit about event delegation...

```js
const
  accordion   = document.querySelector('.accordion')
, accordionEl = accordion.querySelectorAll('.content-container')
  ;
accordion.onclick = ({target: elmAcc}) =>
  {
  if (!elmAcc.matches('.content-container > div.question')) return // select only this div

  let elContainer = elmAcc.closest('.content-container')

  if (elContainer.classList.toggle('active'))
    accordionEl.forEach( panel => panel.classList.toggle('active', panel===elContainer))
  }
  
// clicking outside will close accordion :
document.addEventListener('click', event =>
  {
  if (!accordion.contains(event.target)) 
    accordionEl.forEach( panel => panel.classList.remove('active'))
  });
```

```css
.accordion {
  margin        : 0 auto;
  width         : 60%;
  border-color  : #fff;
  padding       : 2rem;
  border-radius : 30px;
  }
.accordion-title {
  margin-bottom : 2rem;
  text-align    : center;
  }
.accordion .content-container .question {
  padding       : 1rem 0;
  font-size     : 22px;
  cursor        : pointer;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #000;
  position      : relative;
  }
.accordion .content-container .question::after {
  content  : "+";
  position : absolute;
  right    : -5px;
  }
.accordion .answer {
  padding-top : 1rem;
  font-size   : 22px;
  line-height : 1.5;
  width       : 100%;
  height      : 0px;
  overflow    : hidden;
  transition  : all 0.5s;
  }
.accordion .content-container.active .question::after {
  content    : "-";
  font-size  : 2rem;
  transition : 0.5s;
  }
.accordion .content-container.active .answer {
  height : 150px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h2 class="accordion-title">Frequently asked questions</h2>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="question">What is the return Policy</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="question">Where can you find us</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="question">Some other text</div>
    <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolores non eaque beatae dolor veniam amet, molestiae neque quibusdam ipsa!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can i ask few questions? 

i am beginner and I dont understand few things:

 why does this have empty return

if (!elmAcc.matches('.content-container > div.question')) return

and what does this statement in if do (does this return true boolean?)
(elContainer.classList.toggle('active') in 

 if (elContainer.classList.toggle('active'))
 accordionEl.forEach( panel => panel.classList.toggle('active', panel===elContainer))

Comment: @FilipDrábek `if (!elmAcc.matches(...) return` : this is a simple return function, the following code is therefore ignored if the condition is met.

Comment: @FilipDrábek  `if (elContainer.classList.toggle('active'))` yes, the `classList.toggle()` method returns a boolean value (true if the class is added) ; all this is present in the [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)